# Create-react-app создает только папку проекта, node_modules, package.json и package.lock

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, node-modules

Ввожу команду в терминале npx create-react-app maksim, устанавливается, но в итоге набор разворачивается не полностью.

На скриншоте видно что нет ни src, ни app, ни css, ни app

Текущие версии: 
nodejs - 12.16.3
npm - 6.14.4

[image: На скриншоте видно что нет ни src и т. д.]

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть связано с тем, что create-react-app проинсталлирован глобально;
По последним рекомендациям этого делать не следует (чтобы при инсталляции бралась последняя версия)

*If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using* `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` *to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.*